# Может ли речь в кавычках писаться со строчной буквы?

Tags: орфография, прямая-речь, строчная, заглавная

Ребята. На ум пришёл вопрос о букве в кавычках: а бывают ли случаи, когда речь в кавычках с маленькой буквы начинается? Конечно, как мы помним и видим, слова в кавычках берут начало с заглавной буквы.

Однако нужна ли эта заглавная буква в предложении: "Взглядом он пронзил и развеял его гордость, будто говоря: «Сегодня не твой день»"? Вроде бы есть речь в кавычках, но это не слова, произнесённые буквально. Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза в кавычках может писаться со строчной буквы, если она является частью придаточного предложения:
**Взглядом он пронзил и развеял его гордость, будто говоря, что «сегодня не твой день».**